# asp.net mvc 3: deployment. getJson urls don't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, getjson

I have a very simple asp.net mvc3 app that uses jquery::getJSON to call into my controller and get some data top display via jquery::tmpl.

```
function ajaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
}
....

    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false,
        error: ajaxError // tell me what the error was
    });

    var cl = $("#listcontainer");
    $(cl).empty();
    $.getJSON("/Home/GetSomeData", { oldData: "" }, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            var t = $("#listitem").tmpl(item);
            $(cl).append(t);
        });
    });
```

Everything works ok under IIS express, however When I deploy the app to a freshly setup iis7 on win2k8 r2, the getJSON call fails with the error "Not Found" being displayed via the ajaxError function. (the actual app runs ok otherwise).

I can actually call the action from the browser by typing it in - http://webservername/myapp/Home/GetSomeData - and it returns the json to me.

Is this a configuration error? Or am I not supposed to be doing it like this?

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that your URLs are hardcoded and don't contain the virtual directory you're working from.

Rather than hardcode your URLs you should look at using the routing built into MVC.

You can use the `Action` method of the `UrlHelper` to generate links for you such as:

```
Url.Action("GetSomeData","Home")
```

So that:

```
$.getJSON(@Url.Action("GetSomeData","Home"),[...]
```

Comment: Thats brilliant thanks, works without a hitch. ps i'm not sure who down voted you, if it was me it was a errant click. tia.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `UrlHelper` like below to generate the correct URL in both cases:

```
Url.Action("GetSomeData", "Home")
```

If using razor this would end up like:

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetSomeData", "Home")", { oldData: "" }, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        var t = $("#listitem").tmpl(item);
        $(cl).append(t);
    });
});
```