# stopPropagation doesn't work on nested element inside link

Tags: javascript, events, nested, stoppropagation

Please, try the example below. The first anchor has a URL defined as href. When I click the nested span ("heart"), the link is followed by the browser whereas I used the stopPropagation() method.

When the `href` value is set to "#" as in the second example, the propagation is properly stopped. I'm testing on Firefox 47, but I think it is the same in Chrome.

Can anybody can explain this behaviour and how to fix it (I do need the use of only 1 `<a>` and a nested element (span) inside ) ?

PS: please do not remark on the use if `<h3>` into `<a>` tags : this is not the problem, and HTML5 allows me to write this.

PS 2: When I insert this code into jsFiddle I don't experience the same issue.

### My HTML5 Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<script
              src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("a").on("click", function(e) {
        alert("Link");
        });

    $("a span").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        // Updated code : If I add this Ajax Request. the "return false" instruction doesn't work anymore
         $.getJSON('http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_MYSQL.php', {
              option1: ''
            }, function(response) {
            alert('Heart after getSon');
        }); 

        // Doesn't fix the problem if getJson before
        return false;
        }
        );

});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    span {display:inline-block;width:30%;margin:0 auto;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;background-color:#000;}
</style>

</head>
<body>


<a href="http://www.ewample.com" style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid #999;text-align:center;">

    <h3>Link with href</h3>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <span>Heart</span>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</a>


<a href="#" style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid #999;text-align:center;">

    <h3>Link without href (only #)</h3>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <span>Heart</span>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your intended behavior correctly, try adding `return false;` at the end of your span's click function.

```
$(function() {
    $("a span").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("Heart");
        return false;
    });
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        alert("Link");
    });
});
```

EDIT: I believe I know the problem. According to the jQuery docs at:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol.

The problem here is that you are trying to retrieve data from a different domain. Your browser is refusing to retrieve data from that domain, and therefore the code within your `getJSON()` function is not being run. Try using some JSON from your own domain and see if that solves it.

Comment: To be honnest, in my production code I already use this "return false", and I forgot it in my example. I Tried and it works well.... BUT ...
I need to perform an Ajax request before I my real use case. 
I have updated my html markup to show you this request make the "retun false" useless.

Comment: OK, there was a mistake into the parameters passed to the Json request. It's working properly in this example. So I don't understand why it is not working on my production site.

Comment: It's possible something else is blocking it from working properly. Do you have any other code that acts on a or span?

Comment: When I use the Firefox debugger, I can see the code parsing until the return false correctly. And after that.... hummm actually, it is working on my production environnement but not on my desktop... this is just unbelievable

Comment: I think the problem is related to browser security, ajax generally isn't allowed to request data from different domains, so I believe the problem is being caused by you getting your JSON from w3schools rather than locally. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: In my real use case, The data is retrieved from the same server.
The w3scool json data is used only as an example.
However, I'm using localhost host or *.preprod.local domains (added in my windows hosts file) to test... both of these hosts might have special security policies...

Comment: Are you using a WAMP or XAMPP or something similar to run a local webserver, or just opening the file locally? With the latter, it's common for ajax to be blocked on local files.

Comment: I am using IIS and ASP MVC

Comment: In that case, it may be an issue of hardcoded URLs, those tend to have issues in such an environment. Check out the answers to this question and see if it helps you out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7042410/3865851

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I am only issuing the problem on my desktop and my preprod environment. On my production website, the propagation is correctly stopped. I can't understand why, but I cannot spend more time on this.